# jQuery JSON error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my first experience with using JSON so I'm probably doing something really dumb.

I built an app to scrape pages and return a JSON object.

My JSON returned looks like this (using Facebook as an example):

```
{"urlTitle":"Welcome to Facebook \u2014 Log in, sign up or learn more","urlDescription":" Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, post links and videos, and learn more about the people they meet."}
```

However, in FireBug I get the above error (also see screenshot).

My jQuery code gets the JSON via AJAX and looks simple right now:

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function(){ 


        $.ajax({

           url: '/miscellaneous/scrape/scrape.cfm',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {
              strURL:  $.param( $("#submitURL").attr("value") )
           },
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(data) {
               alert("yes!");
           }

        });

    return false;

});
```

I never get my success message :( Just the error!

Am I doing something really obviously wrong here?

Thanks,
Michael.

[image]

EDIT

Here's my entire JSON as requested:

```
{"urlTitle":"Welcome to Facebook \u2014 Log in, sign up or learn more","urlImages":{"image_8":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yb\/r\/GsNJNwuI-UM.gif","image_6":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc7\/v85005\/226\/255889644513526\/app_104_255889644513526_1061222291.png","image_7":"http:\/\/secure-us.imrworldwide.com\/cgi-bin\/m?ci=ent156564&am=3&ep=1&at=view&rt=banner&st=image&ca=cmp7747&cr=crv72918&pc=plc220331&r=1346702536","image_4":"http:\/\/photos-a.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc7\/v85006\/156\/156324174503268\/app_104_156324174503268_1504955413.png","image_5":"http:\/\/photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc7\/v85005\/78\/344521295633922\/app_104_344521295633922_1943760717.png","image_3":"http:\/\/photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc7\/v85005\/14\/298987460188718\/app_104_298987460188718_170436975.png","image_2":"http:\/\/photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net\/photos-ak-snc7\/v85006\/196\/287530028007964\/app_104_287530028007964_853932327.png","image_1":"http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yY\/r\/2LiCtrj0cdC.png"},"urlDescription":" Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, post links and videos, and learn more about the people they meet."}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the json file? Seems to. Me that it might be malformed.

Comment: That's an error Sizzle throws. You're probably somehow passing the JSON as a selector like `$(json)`.

Comment: The JSON is valid: http://jsfiddle.net/esRtf/. As pimvdb already said, it looks more like a Sizzle error. *edit:* it's still valid: http://jsfiddle.net/esRtf/1/. You must be doing something with the data that you are not showing to us.

Comment: always quote your data in jquery ajax requests

Comment: Yes, the error seems to flag on the jQuery UI library and if I remove this (which isn't needed) the error then shows in jQuery itself (not my code). I'm using jQuery 1.8.0

Comment: Ok, this was my own fault. My jQuery file was cached and wasn't sending the right output. Doh!

Comment: I am having the same problem. Can you explain what was wrong and how you fixed it?

Comment: I cannot remember now, but I had an old JSON file cached. Clear your cache and try again!

Comment: You don't need the $.param

Comment: Your json seems valid, but you don't have to escape the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Based on the comments on your question.. looks like you are looking for a way to avoid AJAX requests to do caching. For that you can try something like this..

```
$.ajax({
       url: url,
       data: inputs + '&ran=' + Math.rand(),
    )};
```

or

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

I hope this will help you.